# How to implement custom class level Constraint Validation without Annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I use the `javax.validation` and have a Hibernate validator on a classpath.
I would like to validate entities of a specific class on the class level (not fields level).
I can do this with by creating a custom class-level annotation and a paired `ConstraintValidator` as shown below:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface CustomConstraintAnnotation {
}
```

```
class CustomValidator 
    implements ConstraintValidator<CustomConstraintAnnotation, Object> {
}
```

However, I would like to avoid creating a custom annotation and assign a custom validator per entity type, so that the validator would be registered for this type and validate instances of this type by default when `validator.validate(entity)` is invoked without having to annotate the type.

The `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` does not fit, because it works only in pair with an annotation.
Basically, I would like to create a mapping between the type and the corresponding custom validator without using an annotation.

Is there a way to achieve this?